# cleaning up data/objects after exiting from function/event handler to system

Tags: c++, destructor

recently, I've just learned that there are some cases where the program C++ does not end/exit at the "main" function "return" keyword. From my understanding, this raises the task to do manual clean up of objects and data in the program... of course to have a proper clean up

therefore, in case I have to write a destructor/cleaning up function for a program to replace for the default cleaning up, what should be considered? e.g. all object's destructors? dynamic memory variables? ... any else?

Comment: actually, from some reading, I mostly understand that a clean up including calling destructor of all currently used objects and cleaning up of dynamically allocated data/objects using delete. Am I understanding right?

Comment: Are you asking if you quit the app does your memory get cleaned up? Say for example using `exit(int)`?

Comment: Check this answer about stack unwinding and RAII: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2331413/92957

Comment: @Dragon: this is one comment of someone in SO "Using exit is not nice. It breaks all those RAII objects that we have spent time building correctly. It is a lot nicer to throw back to main. If on the other hand the program is corrupted you should really call std::terminate()"

Comment: even so, they continued to reject all methods of exiting the program, since functions like exit, terminate, abort don't do the clean up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038302/how-do-i-make-a-c-console-program-exit