# How to cause a C++ program to exit

Tags: c++, exit

I'm trying to make my C++ program exit.

I know I can pause input with `while cin >> s`, but I don't know what to do to make the entire program exit.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    long int l;
    long int i;

    char s[100000];

    while (cin >> s)
    {
        l = strlen(s);//strlen Returns the length of the C string str. 


        for (i = 0; i<l; i++)
        {
            switch (s[i])
            {
            case 'W':
                cout << "Q";    break;
            case 'E':
                cout << "W";    break;
            case 'R':
                cout << "E";    break;
            default:
                cout << ";";    break;
            }

        }
        cout << (" ");
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a C++ console program exit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038302/how-do-i-make-a-c-console-program-exit)

Comment: The code is C++, not C; I've fixed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Your program will terminate when it runs out of input.

The `system("pause");` seems to imply that you're using Microsoft Windows.  To signal an end-of-file condition for keyboard input on Windows, type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. (For Linux and other Unix-like systems, use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at the beginning of a line.)

Incidentally, the program you posted is complete and will not compile. That can be corrected by adding the following lines to the top:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
```

When posting a question, please include the entire program.

Comment: this is what i have before the int main -> #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the program to exit by using the command `exit(0);` within the while loop.

Here is my finished program:

```
include iostream
include string
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long int l;
    long int i;

    char s[100000];

    cout << "\n Write your code in UpperCase, " 
    cout << "to close the program switch to LowerCase \n" << endl;

    while (cin >> s)
    {
        l = strlen(s);//strlen Returns the length of the C string str. 

        for (i = 0; i<l; i++)
        {
            switch (s[i])
            {
            case 'W':
                cout << "Q";    break;
            case 'E':
                cout << "W";    break;
            case 'R':
                cout << "E";    break;
            default:
                exit(0);   break;
            }
        }
        cout << (" ");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your loop is waiting until `cin >> s` returns an "end of file" (`EOF`). You can accomplish this on Windows by typing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> or on Unix-like systems such as Mac and Linux <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

You could also put a break character in your loop, or change the condition altogether.

Comment: No, `cin >> s` isn't always going to be true. Checking for an end-of-file condition on standard input is an extremely common thing to do, and it's exactly what this program does. The condition on the `while` loop is perfectly correct as it is.

Comment: I realize that. I accounted for this in my answer. However, judging by the asker's original post, I'd say she is not aware of this. I recommended adding a break for a more common key or changing the condition altogether because it seems more logical for what she is trying to accomplish.

Comment: The code is clearly intended to terminate when it sees an end-of-file condition on standard input. The OP doesn't know how to make that happen. I suggest that telling the OP about Ctrl-Z (which is not some obcure technicality as you suggest) is a better solution than changing the code. It also makes it possible to redirect the program's input from a file or pipe.

Comment: Fine. I guess you win.

Comment: I'm not trying to "win", just answering the OP's question.